# array merge for numeric values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays,

```
Array 1(
  'A' => string '13' (length=2)
  'B' => string '13' (length=2)
)

Array 2(
   9 => string '13' (length=2)
)
```

But when I use `array_merge` to combine these `arrays`, it shows me like this

```
Array(
   'A' => string '13' (length=2)
   'B' => string '13' (length=2) 
    0 => string '13' (length=2)
)
```

Everytime when there is numeric value, in `array_merge` it increments automatically, not taking original value.

Comment: As per the docs: http://php.net/array_merge   `... will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = array('A' => 13, 'B' => 13);
$b = array('9' => 13);

print_r($a+$b);
?>
```

Comment: 1+. Nice clean answer.

Comment: @praveen...Thanks for a cool idea...nice & straight answer....

Comment: @dev if its correct then you should accept it

Comment: @Praveenkalal ya sure...i have also tried before couple of minutes but it didn't, but i have selected it right now....

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() will do the reindexing on the numeric indexes..
You you just want to append one array to other without and reindexing or shuffling use "+" then ...as shown  below

```
<?php
$array1 = array('a'=>'13','b'=>'14');
$array2 = array(9=>'13');
$merged_array  = $array1+$array2;
print_r($merged_array);
?>
```

Documentation link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php